# delete in from DB from R

Tags: r, rmysql

I am trying to delete data from R in mysql table with the data range

Actual statement :

```
dbSendQuery(conn,"delete from tab_name  where date<='2018-07-29'")
```

tried with :

```
    conn = dbConnect(MySQL(),user ="user_id",password = "pwd",dbname ="db_name",host ="localhost")

    a="2018-07-29"
    query <-"delete from table tab_name where date <= "
    dbSendQuery(conn,paste0( query,"'",a,"'"))
```

The error I am getting is:

> Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) : 
>     could not run statement:

Any hints?

Comment: Your query looks fine to me.  Please check your connection settings.  Can you do a basic select using the same credentials?

Comment: @Tim, Thanks , I have checked and working fine with actual statement : dbSendQuery(conn,"delete from tab_name  where date<='2018-07-29'")

Comment: This isn't reproducible then, because I checked your concatenated query string, and it's fine.

Comment: Thanks all, i got answer, its syntax error (by eliminating "table" from query statement.Thanks all for replies